# How to get value of optional parameters from a url with regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have some uris which I want to extract parameters if they are exist, I come up with this code. Can someone point me to fix regex to success.

cityId and countryId works as expected but Cant get only numbers after word '-a-'

[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/ndfe8l/1)

```
// "/city/berlin-a-10284?cityId=123456&countryId=4545"
// "/city/berlin-a-10284"
// "/city/berlin-a-10284?cityId=123456"
// "/city/berlin-a-10284?countryId=4545"



private String ValueExtractor(String url, String searchWord) {

        String regex = "(?<=" + searchWord + ").*?(?=&|$)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(url);

        return matcher.find() ? matcher.group() : "";
}


String productId = "";
String cityId = "";
String countryId = "";

if (url.contains("-p-")) {
    productId = ValueExtractor(url, "-a-");
}

if (url.contains("cityId")) {
    cityId = ValueExtractor(url, "cityId=");

}

if (url.contains("countryId")) {
    countryId = ValueExtractor(url, "countryId=");

}
```

Expected results:

```
"/city/berlin-a-10284?cityId=123456&countryId=4545" 
productId:10284
cityId: 123456
countryId: 4545

"/city/berlin-a-10284"
productId:10284

"/city/berlin-a-10284?cityId=123456"
productId:10284
cityId: 123456

"/city/berlin-a-10284?countryId=4545"
productId:10284
countryId: 4545
```

Comment: `new URI( string ).getPath()` would be a better start.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html#getPath()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cant get only numbers after word '-a-'

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/ZAtCow/1), `(?<=-a-)\d+(?=[?&]|$)` to retrieve this number.

- `(?<=-a-)\d+` specifies one or more digits preceded by `-a-`.
- `(?=[?&]|$)` specifies positive lookahead for `?`, or `&` or end of line.

Comment: But regex seems like a poor tool for parsing URIs.  Wouldn't using the `URI` class be better?

Comment: @markspace - URI classes would definitely be better if the full path or parameters are to be extracted. In this particular case, the OP is looking to get a part of the path.

Comment: The OP also has a query string attached to the path in some cases.  I really think using URI for parsing the path and the query would be better.

Comment: @markspace - I respect your concern but I am being lazy to post another answer after getting tired of the whole day's work . If you have time, please post an answer.